# Database Records Order

Tags: c#, database, hyperlink, windows-phone, records

i am developing an application for windows phone in c# using sql compaq for database in order to make it simple as plug and play.

The problem is that if i delete a record in my database and make an new insert the record is displayed at the position of deleted record and not at the bottom as last inserted.

Note that i dont have any column which can be used for ordering as id or some date column to sort and get the rows in fifo.
The important thing is to not add any other column in this database to make the sorting, i am trying to find a way to change this behavior.

I searched a lot to make a sort with the order of the insertments but i didn't found anything as database does not relocate the rows after a deletion because uses the empty space of deleted record in order to use less the disk.

So how can i make the records display in the same way they were inserted?

Comment: What database? Could you show the code that inserts the new record?

Comment: Can you show us the table schema?

Comment: [table(1)]->[columns(url, name, type)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guaranteed database "order".  You need to specify a sort field with `Order By`.

If this is really a requirement, then as you suggest a monotonically increasing primary key integer or `createdOn` column is required

Comment: Thanks, it seems that there is not a possible way to get the rows from database if I do not have a increment key.